# "inplace" wrapper for shell commands

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed

Is is possible to write a shell script `./inplace` which works as
follows:

```
./inplace arg1 arg2 [..] argn
```

should be equivalent to the sequence:

```
arg1 arg2 [..] argn > tmp.file
mv tmp.file argn
```

For three arguments:

```
./inplace arg1 arg2 arg3
```

should work as

```
arg1 arg2 arg3 > tmp.file
mv tmp.file arg3
```

My attempts are failing for cases with arguments involving `$1`. For
example

```
 ./inplace awk '{print $1}' file.txt
```

**Update:**

This works (following an answer from Thomas Dickey)

```
#!/bin/sh

for last; do true; done

"$@" > tmp.file
mv tmp.file "${last}"

# Examples:
#
# seq 20 > test.txt
# ./inplace.sh head test.txt
# cat test.txt
#
# seq 20 > test.txt
# ./inplace.sh awk '{print $1^2}' test.txt
# cat test.txt
#
# seq 20 > test.txt
# ./inplace.sh awk -v line="with spaces:" '{print line, $1}' test.txt
# cat test.txt
#
```

Comment: Very clever!  <dummy character>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Likely the problem is lack of quoting.  If you use the special parameter `"$@"` in the `inplace` script (rather than `$*` for instance), it will quote all of the parameters.